# Reorganize text block to csv - python

Tags: python, csv

i hope someone can help me. I have a text file which contains details about switches, but i need the information in a CSV readable format. Currently the details are in a text block, and each device is delimited by dashes.

Here is an example of the data before:

```
Device ID: FQDN1.domain.com
IP address: 192.168.1.1
Platform: cisco IE-3200-8P2S
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/2/3
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/1
-------------------------
Device ID: FQDN1.domain.com
IP address: 192.168.1.1
Platform: cisco IE-3200-8P2S
Interface: GigabitEthernet2/2/3
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/2
-------------------------
....
```

---

And this is what i would like to get out:

```
Device ID, IP address, Platform, Interface, Port ID
FQDN1.domain.com, 192.168.1.1, cisco IE-3200-8P2S, GigabitEthernet1/2/3, GigabitEthernet1/1
FQDN1.domain.com, 192.168.1.1, cisco IE-3200-8P2S, GigabitEthernet2/2/3, GigabitEthernet1/2
```

---

I already tried something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
with open(r'file.txt','r') as file:
    data=file.read().split('\n\n')
data=[i.split('\n') for i in data]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Device ID','IP address','Platform','Interface','Port ID (outgoing port)'])

print(df)
```

But i get the error ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 10 columns

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def parse_switches_to_csv():
    with open('switches.txt') as fin:
        text = fin.read()

    entries = text.split("-------------------------")

    with open('switches.csv', 'w') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        writer.writerow(['Device ID','IP address','Platform','Interface','Port ID (outgoing port)'])
        for entry in entries:
            writer.writerow([col.split(": ")[1] for col in entry.split('\n') if col])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Zev Averbach. Unfortunately if i run that code, i get no error message, but the csv file is empty.

Comment: i'm surprised nerz! where is it failing? does `text` have anything in it? same question for `entries`. are there tokens in the "switches" text file that you didn't put in the sample input? did you actually call the function?